# Form submit button to email based on a fields value

Tags: forms, email, conditional-statements

I'm creating a PDF form with a submission button.  I would like the form to email based on the value of another form in the field.  I'm assuming I need to do an "IF...ELSE" statement, but keep getting a syntax error that I cannot figure out. I am completely java illiterate.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using multiple solutions, but you do need to program Javascript inside of the PDF. You can use if-else on-click of the email-button. Here you can check values entered inside of the PDF form:

```
if (this.getValue("somefield") == "left") { emailvalue = "toA@domain.com" } else { emailvalue = "toB@domain.com" }
```

But you could also set the value `onBlur` or `onFocus` of a certain field. Like with radio-buttons the `onBlur` is useful because you know the user clicked or focused on this field and so set the variable `emailvalue` to a certain value.